# How to update json object in a loop?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, object

My end goal is to have a json file in a variable that can be passed to an API. Right now, I can't get the JSON to update how I want it to in the loop. How can I get it to output/append all the options and not just the last in the loop?

```
import json

info = {}

states = ["MN", "AZ", "IL"]
cities = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
votes = ["No", "Yes", "Maybe"]

for state in states:
    for city in cities:
        for vote in votes:
            info.update({'name': 'master', 'state': state, 'cities': {'name': city, 'votes': {'decision': vote}}})

print(json.dumps(info, indent=4))
```

And the output I'm getting is:

```
{
    "name": "master",
    "state": "IL",
    "cities": {
        "name": "Three",
        "votes": {
            "decision": "Maybe"
        }
    }
}
```

But I want it to be:

```
{

    "name": "master",
         {
            "state": "MN",
            "cities": {
                 "name": "One",
                 "votes": {
                            "decision": "No"
                          }
        },
        {
            "state": "MN",
            "cities": {
                 "name": "One",
                 "votes": {
                            "decision": "Yes"
                          }
        }
        
        ....etc.....
    }
}
```

edit: updated desired output

Comment: What you've asked for is not valid JSON.  You need a list in there somewhere to contain your multiple objects.  You'll need to decide what name to use for the list.

Comment: Where in your code do you create keys `votes-1`, `votes-2`, etc.?

Comment: `.update()` only updated the top-level dictionary. Nested dictionaries and lists are replaced, not merged. You can make use of nested `defaultdict()` to assign to nested items.

Comment: @timRoberts - Please see updated desired output

Comment: @Barmar - Please see updated desired output

Comment: Still not valid. You don't have a key for the data after `name`. And that data needs to be in a list.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know how to put in a list and still have it format the way I want?

Comment: The format you want is not valid JSON, so I don't know why you want that format.

Comment: You seem to be confused about the required format. Do you have a link to the API documentation so we can see what it expects?

Comment: It should be something like `{"name": "master", "states": [ { ... }, { ... }, etc.] }`

Comment: @Barmar I don't as it can't be shared. I'm not as concerned with the formatting needed for the api as I am getting it to output all of the items and not just last like it currently does.

Comment: But if you don't give us a valid format, how can we show how to create it? We can't write code that generates invalid JSON.

Comment: @Barmar I understand. It can be formatted as you see fit. Like I said I just need it to output all of the data. The API that's taking in the JSON can be changed/mapped to match in the backend. The issue is it only outputs the last instance of the nested loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put all the state information into a list. Then you can simply append each dictionary to that list. There's nothing to update, since each dictionary is a separate element of the list

```
import json

info = {
    "name": "master",
    "states": []
}

states = ["MN", "AZ", "IL"]
cities = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
votes = ["No", "Yes", "Maybe"]

for state in states:
    for city in cities:
        for vote in votes:
            info['states'].append({
                "state": state,
                "cities": {
                    "name": city,
                    "votes": { "decision": vote }
                }
            });

print(json.dumps(info, indent=4))
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/X9H3Ty)

I wonder, though, if this is really the result you want. You have a key called `cities`; the name suggests that it should contain more than one city, but it only contains one -- you have each city in a separate `state` dictionary. The same thing goes for `votes` -- it's just one vote, not all of the votes for that city.

Comment: Thank you for this!! This helped a lot. In my mind and use case, there will be multiple votes per each different city in each state. But I'm sure this is fine. I got it to at least output all the results. Thank u!